# error : C2664 'void RecursiveDelete(LPWSTR,LPWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const wchar_t [12]' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, c2664

Any Idea how to fix? Would be really useful. I tried changing conformance mode to off and it worked but the other parts of the program failed. Any other fixes?

Line that has problem :

```
RecursiveDelete(path, L"desktop.ini");
```

Edit :

The program is to change windows registry files and is connected with my c++ loader. When the project is standalone not connected to the loader it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215131/discussion-on-question-by-notkrystian-error-c2664-void-recursivedeletelpwstr).

Answer (score 2):

The `RecursiveDelete()` function takes 2 `LPWSTR` parameters.  `LPWSTR` is an alias for `wchar_t*`, ie a pointer to non-const `wchar_t` data.  However, a string literal is `const` data, in this case `L"desktop.ini"` is a `const wchar_t[12]` (including the null terminator), which decays into a `const wchar_t*` pointer.  You can't use a `pointer-to-const` where a `pointer-to-non-const` is expected, that is what the error message is complaining about.

**IF** the function DOES NOT alter the contents of its second parameter, then that parameter *should* be implemented as a `pointer-to-const`, eg:

```
void RecursiveDelete(LPWSTR, LPCWSTR);
```

(aka `void RecursiveDelete(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);`).

If changing the declaration of the function is not an option (ie, it is from an existing API, etc), you could instead cast away the string literal's constness using `const_cast` (be VERY CAREFUL doing this!), eg:

```
RecursiveDelete(path, const_cast<LPWSTR>(L"desktop.ini"));
```

However, making a non-const duplicate of the string literal's data would be much safer, eg:

```
wchar_t copy[] = L"desktop.ini";
RecursiveDelete(path, copy);
```

Comment: By doing this, it doesn't have a definition https://imgur.com/a/hEP6vcf

Comment: Added it now - I mean by doing any of those options

Comment: That error means the compiler can't find a matching declaration of the function, or a matching implementation for the declaration. Did you change the function itself, or maybe forget an `#include` for it? The solution I have given works fine with the declaration shown in the originally error message you provided.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/79kQ4j8 This is the definition of the function

Comment: That is the *definition* (ie, implementation), but what about the *declaration*? In any case, both `dir` and `match` parameters are being treated as read-only, so they should both be changed to `LPCWSTR` if possible. And BTW, the 1st `if` statement inside that implementation should be inside the 2nd `if` block. Also, there is no error handling on the `FileFirstFile()`

Comment: When the project is standalone, there are no errors but when I include it into the main project the error shows up. Could it just be a problem with the project config?

Comment: @NotKrystian then you need to provide a [mcve], because you are clearly doing something we can't see. I answered your original question as it was asked. Whatever problem you are having now is related to something else.  Post it as a separate question.